# Adding filter feGaussianBlur to SVG circle is disappeared on Safari, on Chrome

Tags: html, css, reactjs, svg

I am adding the filter with feGaussianBlur to SVG circle, it works like charm on Chrome, though, the circle disappears on Safari.

[image: chrome working]

[image: Safari not working]

```
     <filter
        id="soft"
        filterRes="1200"
        colorInterpolationFilters="sRGB"
        x="-50%"
        y="-50%"
        width="200%"
        height="200%"
     >
        <feGaussianBlur in="SourceGraphic" stdDeviation="5" />
    </filter>
   {circles.map(circle => {
      return (
        <circle
          r={baseBubbleR}
          style={{
          filter: skillType === 'soft' ? 'url(#soft)' : '',
          fill: circleColor
        />
       )
     })
```

I tried some solution here, like expanding region etc...
Any help appreciated

Comment: Drop the filterRes and the colorInterpolationFilters and see if that works.

Comment: no luck with that. :(, @MichaelMullany

Comment: does the circle render on Safari without the filter?

Comment: Yes, it does render. like normal circle. and I think I am getting close to solve the issue. thanks

Comment: you might have duplicate id's ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to manage this problem and I think this is not exactly SVG issue.

So I had to have different filter for each circle on Safari.
To render each filter properly while global filter worked for different browsers.

```
{circles.map((circle, index) => {
  return (
    <div key={`circle-${index}`}>
      <filter
        id={`circle-${index}`}
        filterRes="1200"
        colorInterpolationFilters="sRGB"
        x="-50%"
        y="-50%"
        width="200%"
        height="200%"
      >
        <feGaussianBlur in="SourceGraphic" stdDeviation="5" />
      </filter>
      <circle
        r={baseBubbleR}
        style={{
        filter: skillType === 'soft' ? 'url(#soft)' : '',
        fill: circleColor
      />
     </div>
   )
 })
```

Above code is just example.

Comment: If you're creating more than one element with the same id i.e. id="soft" then that's invalid and may bite you later.

Comment: @RobertLongson, thanks for pointing that out. actually real code was a bit different with this. updated